# Cant see angular sources in chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

So I am getting errors in my javascript for my angularJS app but I can't see where they are at. If I open the sources tab in the debugger and cant see any of my angularJS stuff. Here is an example of the error I'm getting in my console to prove it:

```
Error: InvalidCharacterError: DOM Exception 5
Error: An invalid or illegal character was specified, such as in an XML name.
    at p.extend.attr (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994), <anonymous>:2:30181)
    at Function.p.extend.access (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994), <anonymous>:2:15973)
    at p.fn.extend.attr (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994), <anonymous>:2:26741)
    at Object.Attributes.$set (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994)), <anonymous>:3775:28)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994)), <anonymous>:4406:15)
    at forEach (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994)), <anonymous>:140:20)
    at mergeTemplateAttributes (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994)), <anonymous>:4401:7)
    at applyDirectivesToNode (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994)), <anonymous>:4149:13)
    at compileNodes (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994)), <anonymous>:3902:15)
    at compile (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js:4:4994)), <anonymous>:3840:29)
```

Notice all the  in the stack trace? Any idea why this is happening? It used to work just fine...

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Chrome Extension for Angular called Batarang: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk